# Prove or disprove: if $3\nmid n$ then $3\mid n^2+2$ where $n\in\Bbb N$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm new to proofs but I was thinking of doing this proof by contradiction where if $n$ isn't divisible by $3$ then $n^2+2$ also isn't divisible by $3$. But I didn't get very far into that proof.

Comment: is it $n^2+2$ or $n^{2+2}$?

Comment: Fixed its $n^{2}+2$

Comment: @Parcly Am I reading this wrong? The statement claims "if $n$ is not divisible by $3$ then $3|(n^2+2)$". You've shown a value for which the claim is true.

Comment: @ElliotG _I'll be answering this!_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every integer can be written in the form $3k,3k+1$ or $3k+2$.We,don't take $n=3k$ case as it is divisible by $3$.

For $n=3k+1$

$$n^2+2=(3k+1)^2+2=9k^2+6k+3=3(3k^2+2k+1).$$

So,it is divisible by $3$.

For $n=3k+2$,

$$n^2+2=(3k+2)^2+2=9k^2+12k+6=3(3k^2+4k+2)$$.So,it is divisible by $3$.

Comment: how did you get $3k+2$?

Comment: The statement claims that $n^2+2$ is divisible by $3$.

Comment: Note that by Euclids Division Lemma we know we can write any any integer in the form $3k,3k+1$ or $3k+2$....

Comment: @ElliotG It's prove or disprove...so it's both way round..:-)

Comment: Right but, using this method, you can show if $n=3k+1$ or $n=3k+2$ then the statement is true.

Comment: Thanks that last edit made it clear for me, I was wondering why you didn't show for $n = 3k+2$ @tatan

Comment: @ElliotG $n=3k+1$,$3k+2$ are  the only possible cases for which $n$ is not divisible by $3$...

Comment: @Krio Then please accept and upvote it....

Comment: @tatan I agree, I was just pointing out that you wrote "disproved" after proving the original claim.

Comment: @ElliotG Sorry...edited and removed it...:-)

Answer (score 0):

We are to prove that

> if $3\nmid n$ then $3\mid n^2+2$.

Any number not divisible by 3 can be written as either $3k+1$ or $3k-1$, where $k$ is an integer. If $n=3k+1$:
$$n^2+2=9k^2+6k+3=3(3k^2+2k+1)$$
If $n=3k-1$:
$$n^2+2=9k^2-6k+3=3(3k^2-2k+1)$$
In both cases, $n^2+2$ can be written as $3m$ where $m$ is an integer. By definition, then, $3$ divides $n^2+2$ and the statement is proved.

Answer (score 0):

2 added to square of remainders of 3 (other than zero), is divisible by 3.

Answer (score 0):

We want to proof: if $3\nmid n$ then $3|n^2+2$.

By Fermat's Little Theorem we have:
If $p\nmid n$ then $n^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$.

Our problem is when $p=3$,
$$n^2\equiv 1 \pmod{3} \to n^2+2\equiv 1+2\equiv 0 \pmod{3}.$$
We are done!

Answer (score 0):

If $3\nmid n \implies n \equiv 1 $ or $n \equiv 2 \space \text{(mod 3)}$. So you have that $$1^{2} + 2 \equiv 3 \equiv 0 \space \text{(mod 3)} $$ $$2^{2} + 2 \equiv 6 \equiv 0 \space \text{(mod 3)}$$